# Django wont let me create a new model object with this view-function. Whats wrong?

Tags: django, forms, view, geodjango

Im submitting a form via POST and Im trying to create a new model object in my data-base with this view in Django. It's not working. Can someone tell me if this function looks OK?

Thank you very much!

```
@csrf_exempt
def UploadTest(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        response = {}

        if form.is_valid():
            response["status"] = "OK"
            new_point = MyModel()
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            coordinates = cd['coordinates'].split(',')
            new_point.pt = Point(float(coordinates[0]), float(coordinates[1]))
            new_point.name = cd['name']
            new_point.point_type = cd['point_type']
            new_point.description = cd['description']
            new_point.save()
        else:
            response["status"] = "bad"
            response.update(form.errors)    

            s = StringIO()
            json.dump(response, s)
            s.seek(0)
            return HttpResponse(s.read())
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form })
```

**UPDATE:** I did not find the problem but instead I recreated my database and it worked! Thanks you all and sorry for taking up your time! Any Admin feel free to delete this POST.

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: Nope. No errors. It's more like nothing happens. No response and it's not creating a new object either. If i clear everything under "if form is valid" except the response i do a response back. So the javascript POST function in my template seems to work.

Comment: You forgot to save the `Point()` - Try saving the `pt` before assiging it to `new_point`

Comment: Is form really valid? Can you confirm the indentation in your post (which I edited)?

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Yes i think the form is valid because i do not get the validation errors and i get them if I leave the fields empty.

Not sure what you mean XORcist? Yes the indentation looks fine. Thanks for editing i had some problems with stackoverflows system..

Comment: karhikr, i tried that but i was not working. (Just to be clear i do not have a model named Point i've just imported that method from django.contrib.gis.geos. But anyways it's not working with or wihtout the save..)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I think you need to use ensure_csrf_cookie() on the view instead of csrf_exempt() since it looks like you are doing an ajax post.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#page-uses-ajax-without-any-html-form

---

Old answer:

Point isn't being saved. You should create it. save it. then set new_point.pt.

```
if form.is_valid():
    response["status"] = "OK"
    new_point = MyModel()
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    coordinates = cd['coordinates'].split(',')
    new_point_object = Point(float(coordinates[0]), float(coordinates[1]))
    new_point_object.save()
    new_point.pt = new_point_object
    new_point.name = cd['name']
    new_point.point_type = cd['point_type']
    new_point.description = cd['description']
    new_point.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer teewuane! I tried you first answer and it was not working :/ I'll check the CSRF thing because i think i've tried it without the point and niether that was working.

Comment: Nah, ensure_csrf_cookie didn't do much difference. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmm. I think you'll probably have to provide more information on your forms and such.

Comment: OK! I added a form and model. Please have a look and see if you see anything wierd.

Answer (score 0):

OK. So except for the Point-save that many has suggested (which i don't think is the root problem here) it shouldn't be any formatting or syntax errors in this function, right? In theory it should work?

Just so I can concentrate on debugging the rest..

This is the same view Im trying to achieve but with some modifications: http://ipasic.com/article/let-user-add-point-map-geodjango-leaflet/

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You're defining `form` inside the `if request.method == "POST"` if statement, meaning that if the request method ISN'T post, form is going to be undefined which will prevent your view function from working.

Edit: ignore me, I missed the `else` statement due to the formatting.